# Putting Headers on Data Files

Tags: list, file, pandas

I have a number of data files of a generic file format, (I say this as I am being given files off of Google Drive, which is messing up all of the formats to throw it all into a "File" file format), which behaves similar to a text format, except it has no .txt afterward or any other file indicator. I have to compare this data to data in NetCDF files. In order to easily do so, I would like to make xarrays from the files that are more like text files, and so I am trying to insert a header for each column in the text files.

I have figured out a way which works in my command line, but does not work when defined as a function, which is truly what is convenient to me as I'll be dealing with quite a few of these files and comparing all of them to data in NetCDF files. I have the following code:

```
def cvrtpa(fle,separation_character,(labels)):
    """
    converts an undefined file into a pandas array file with labels given.

    Parameters
    -----------
    fle: The file with path, name and type of file.
    separation_character: This is the separation method used by the file (i.e. commas in comma deliminated file formats).
    labels: These are the table headers for the data.

    Returns
    -------
    data in a panda array with column headers that are the labels.
    """
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    flabels=np.str(len(labels))
    finlabel = [flabel for flabel in flabels + separation_character]
    finalabel=''    
    for i in xrange(len(finlabel)):
        finalabel+=str(finlabel[i])
    mfile=open(fle,'r+')
    mfile.seek(0)
    mfile.write(finalabel+'\n')
    mfile.close()
    data=pd.read_csv("fle")
    return data

fl='.../Summer 2016/Data/Test/Test'
label=['Year','Month','Day','Hour','Minute','Precipitation']
xx=cvrtpa(fl,'.0',label)
```

After which, I get the following error:

> IOError: File does not exist

I have tested this in the command prompt and have successfully written to the Test file without any problem. I do not understand why this function is not working.

Comment: It should be `data=pd.read_csv(fle)` (remove the quotes).

Comment: Wow... I don't know how I didn't see that... Thank you.